# Would this method find the non-shortest induced path in a graph $G$ in $O(n^2\ln n)$?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Let $u,v$ be fixed vertices in $G$.

1. Find the shortest $u \to v$ path $p$ by Dijkstra.
2. Remove each edge of $p$ from $G$ one by one and apply Dijkstra on $G \setminus \{e\}$ for each edge $e \in p$ each time, until you get a $u \to v$ path.

Comment: What is meant by "non-shortest"/?

Comment: You will likely find the [Wiki discussion on snake-in-the-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake-in-the-box) helpful

Comment: @coffeemath non shortest means a path that is not the shortest. An alternative path. Where it exists and can we find it in the above complexity by the above method?

Comment: If there are 3 or more distinct paths, then "not the shortest" has no unique meaning. So do you really want to find *any* path which is not the shortest? or maybe find a path which is the shortest among all but the shortest?

Answer (score 1):

You do find a path that is not shortest. Note that for two different $u$-$v$-paths $P$ and $Q$, we cannot have $P\subset Q$ because then $Q\setminus P$ would need to consist of cycles.

Now let $Q$ be the shortest path. By the observation above, there is an edge $e\in E(P)$ that is not contained in $Q$, so $E(Q)\subset E\setminus\{e\}$ for this edge. Doing this for all edges of path, we end up with one such $Q$ if it exists. In fact, you can get the "second best" (or more specifically, the best that is not $P$) by taking the shortest path among the paths you obtain from the second step.

One small detail about the runtime: You would actually get $\mathcal{O}(m+n^2\log n)$ which obviously is the same as you say if $G$ is a simple graph. But in general, you would need an edge-scanning first to omit parallel edges if these exist.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @Ekin 's answer I would like to point out that the algorithm doesn't take ties into account. Assume there are two distinct but optimal $u,v$ paths. Your algorithm will return one of them. As an example, take $ G = C_{2n}$ and $u,v$ be any two antipodal points. Apparently, in this graph there aren't any non optimal paths so simply add a path of length $n+1$ between $u$ and $v$